# Find files by creation/modification date then moving to another dir in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, move, last-modified, shutil

First question. I am new to programming, much less python. As the title says I am attempting to find files that were created or modified in the past 24 hours, then move those files to another directory. I can find the files but I can't figure out how to move the files that meet this criteria. My script so far:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('source\folder'):

    for file_name in files:
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        before = now - dt.timedelta(hours=24)
        path = os.path.join(root,file_name)
        st = os.stat(path)

        mod_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_ctime)
        if mod_time < before:
            print('%s modified %s'%(path,mod_time))
```

I've attempted to use shutil to move the output but I get an error;

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found
```

I've tried to find a solution online but haven't had any luck. Not even sure if I can do what I am trying to do with the way I have this constructed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're passing `shutil` a `datetime.datetime` object instead of a string with the filename. Can you show the code that you were using in that attempt?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was attempting to use shutil like this: shutil.move(mod_time, 'dest\path')

Comment: As I suspected, you're moving the date. You need to move the file.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's what I thought but I am unsure how to get the results and apply that to the files that need to be moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
shutil.move(mod_time, 'dest\path')
```

do:

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file_name), 'dest\path')
```

This passes that function a filename instead of a date.

Comment: I've tried this as well. I get : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'

Comment: We'll have to combine the name with the directory path. Give me a minute.

Comment: You're the bee's knees. I've been trying to sort this out for over a day & I am at a loss.

Comment: @RyanHenry - Glad to hear it! You can mark this answer as having solved your issue by clicking the check mark below the score.

Comment: Many times thanks. I would not have come to this solution on my own.